# Using two fields from different class hierarchy routes for map-filter lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

We have a method which receives an object of the class on the top of the class hierarchy. It uses a condition based on a field somewhere deeper in the hierarchy, and if that is fulfilled then it uses for a builder another field also somewhere deeper in the hierarchy but on a different route starting from the top class.

```
public Optional<SomeType> create(final TopClassInHierarchy topClass) {
  Optional<SomeType> someObject = Optional.empty();
  if (someCondition.evaluate(getFieldOne(topClass))) {
      someObject = Optional.of(new SomeType.Builder()
              .withFieldTwo(getFieldTwo(topClass))
              .build());
  }
  return someObject;

private FieldOne getFieldOne(TopClassInHierarchy topClass) { return topClass.getSomething()...getFieldOne();
private FieldTwo getFieldTwo(TopClassInHierarchy topClass) { return topClass.getSomethingElse()...getFieldTwo();
```

We would like to preferably condense this into one statement, something like this

```
SomeType.Builder builder = new SomeType.Builder();
Optional.of(topClass)
        .map(this::getFieldOne)
        .filter(someCondition::evaluate)
        .map(this::getFieldTwo) //???
        .ifPresent(builder::withFieldTwo);
```

However, once we map topClass down to fieldOne for the condition evaluation, afterwards we don't seem to be able to "step back" to topClass to map it down to fieldTwo for the builder. Is this feasible with one statement?

Comment: Do you need the first `map`? Is it possible to call `filter(topC -> someCondition.evaluate(topC.getFieldOne()))`. If the filter is passed, you can map to `getFieldTwo`. Or did I get you wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think this should work:

```
public Optional<SomeType> create(final TopClassInHierarchy topClass) {
  Builder builder = new Builder();

  return Optional.of(topClass)
    .filter(tc -> someCondition.evaluate(getFieldOne(tc)))
    .map(tc -> builder.withFieldTwo(getFieldTwo(tc)).build());
}
```

`someCondition.evaluate` in `filter` needs `fieldOne` as input, but to keep `topClass` as the current state of the `Optional` we do not `map` to `fieldOne`. Instead the method `getFieldOne` is used. If the filter is passed we can map `topClass` to the result of the `builder` applied on `fieldTwo` retrieved by the method `getFieldTwo`.

Or with more intermediate mappings:

```
public Optional<SomeType> create(final TopClassInHierarchy topClass) {
    Builder builder = new Builder();

    return Optional.of(topClass)
            .filter(tc -> someCondition.evaluate(getFieldOne(tc)))
            .map(this::getFieldTwo)
            .map(builder::withFieldTwo)
            .map(Builder::build);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent solution. With some refactoring of our code we could eventually simplify this idea down to as much as `return Optional.of(topClass).filter(this::evaluateCondition).map(this::buildSomeTypeObject)`

Comment: I'm glad I understood your question and could help.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be able to say something like:

```
.map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(this.getFieldOne(x), this.getFieldTwo(x)))
.filter(e -> evaluateTheCondition(e.getKey()))
.map(Entry::getValue)
.ifPresent(builder::withFieldTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you don't need getFieldOne you shouldn't map to it otherwise you can not get back to map for another getFieldTwo; i suggest you to first use filter without Method Referencing and the if it evaluates to true map tto getFieldTwo:

```
Optional.of(entity)
                .filter(p->someCondition.evaluate(p.getSomething().getFieldOne()))
                .map(this::getFieldTwo) 
                .ifPresent(builder::withFieldTwo);
```